# How to apply unique count among all the months in PowerBI table visual?

Tags: powerbi, count-unique

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a table visual as shown in the screenshot above. The `Total` number of new students shown in the table visual is 210. However, when I manually sum the value, i.e. `20+27+25+31+...+41`, i get 216 instead of 210.

I'm using `student-id` in the table visual and apply `Count (Distinct)` on it. I guess the potential reason that cause the discrepancy is because of the `Count (Distinct)` is apply on monthly basis, so it just make sure in that particular month, there is no duplicated `student-id`. However, when it moved to next month, it will ignore the `student-id` that appeared in previous month.

For the `Total = 210`in the table visual, I guess the `Count (Distinct)` will work across all the months to make sure that the `student-id` is unique from January to August.

May I know how should I make sure that the `student-id` only appeared once from January to August and hence show the total value of 210? Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

### Sample data

```
student_id    month
100            Jan
101            Jan
102            Jan
100            Feb
103            Mar
101            Mar
104            Feb
100            Jan
```

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: please share some dummy data and formulas you've used so far, so we can have an idea about the fact table & check ...

Comment: check for [ALLEXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allexcept-function-dax)

Comment: @UmutK I added sample data in my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try powerquery

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQwUNJR8krMU4rVAfEMUXhGKDyQSrfUJCjPGMjzTSxC0ofgmaCohNsQCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [student_id = _t, month = _t]),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source, {"student_id"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"month"}, {{"Number of Students", each Table.RowCount(Table.Distinct(_)), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image: number of students]

Answer (score 0):

You should create a measure to count the student-ids and allow your slicers to do the filtering for you.

```
NewStudents=distinctcount(‘Table1’[Student-ID])
```

Now drop that measure into your table in place of the Number of New Students column that is currently shown.

Comment: It seems like still the same